# How to add properties to a JSON in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, properties

I have the following code:

```
type DailySummaryEntrry = {date: string, summary: ParsedSummary};

function parseDailySummaries (summaries: DailyRawSummaries): DailySummaryEntrry[] {
  const entries: DailySummaryEntrry[] = [];

  for (const date in summaries) {
    const rawSummary = summaries[date];
    if (!rawSummary) continue;
    entries.date = date ;
    entries.summary= parseRawSummary(rawSummary);
  }
  return entries.sort().reverse(); // sort by newest date first
}
```

I don't know why do I get

`Property 'date' does not exist on type 'DailySummaryEntrry[]'.deno-ts(2339)`

at this line
`entries.date = date ;`

and:

```
Property 'summary' does not exist on type 'DailySummaryEntrry[]'.deno-ts(2339)
```

At this line

```
entries.summary= parseRawSummary(rawSummary);
```

Comment: `const entries: DailySummaryEntrry[]` So it's an array - and arrays don't have a `.date` property. Did you mean to navigate to one of the objects inside the array? Also `entries.sort()` won't work, since you have an array of objects, not an array of strings or numbers

Comment: You have a very strange code. Post a json at least to show what are you trying to reach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following for loop:

```
  for (const date in summaries) {
    const rawSummary = summaries[date];
    if (!rawSummary) continue;
    entries.date = date ;
    entries.summary= parseRawSummary(rawSummary);
  }
```

`entries` is an array. the date property and summary property dont exist on an array. What you could do instead is the following:

```
  for (const date in summaries) {
    const rawSummary = summaries[date];
    if (!rawSummary) continue;
    entries.push({date: date, summary: parseRawSummary(rawSummary)})
  }
```

Comment: That is so strange, because I think I tried your suggestion at the first time but it didn't work, but now it worked!